# sql query in ascending value not working as expected

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL query to output movies with an odd numbered ID and a description that is not 'boring' and also Order the result by rating.

```
    +---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
    |   id    | movie     |  description |  rating   |
    +---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
    |   1     | War       |   great 3D   |   8.9     |
    |   2     | Science   |   fiction    |   8.5     |
    |   3     | irish     |   boring     |   6.2     |
    |   4     | Ice song  |   Fantacy    |   8.6     |
    |   5     | House card|   Interesting|   9.1     |
    +---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

For the example above, the output should be:

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|   id    | movie     |  description |  rating   |
+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|   5     | House card|   Interesting|   9.1     |
|   1     | War       |   great 3D   |   8.9     |
```

My sql query looks like the following however it does not appear to be arranging them in order by rating. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT *
from cinema
WHERE ( id % 2 ) != 0
  and description != 'boring'
ORDER BY rating ASC;
```

This is returning the movies in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ORDER BY rating DESC` instead of `ASC`.

Descending means highest first, ascending means lowest first. You want high-rated first.

Comment: THANKS MAN! That worked, i was sure I tried that aswell ;-S